# iMac Yosemite to iPad Air or Air 2

Tags: photos, data-transfer

Can I share individual JPEG photos  from my iMac Yosemite to my iPad Air or Air2, or must I email them to the iPad? I am thinking of buying the latter to use at my desk while painting and need to be able to enlarge portions of the photo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iCloud Photo Library to transfer these photos. Just import the photos to the Photos application and make sure that iCloud Photo Library is enabled in your iCloud preferences.